# Jsoup select() return nothing in Android application

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm making an Android app for my board community. The board provider gives me RSS feeds from general categories but don't generate feeds from topics. So I retreive topics URLs from these feeds and want to parse HTML with Jsoup and give it to a WebView.

It works nice except with the select() function which returns nothing.

The "HTML RETREIVED" log gives me : `<html><head><title>The topic title</title></head><body></body></html>`

h1 tags are in the code on test purpose : it displays well on WebView and the title of the parsed webpage too.

I also putted the log line right after the select() line. It returns nothing too.

I've tried in a pure Java project to parse with Jsoup only and it goes well.
So I assumed something's wrong with Android.

PS : Internet permission is active in the manifest.

Did I miss something ?

Here is the code :

```
String html;
     Bundle param = this.getIntent().getExtras();
     String url = param.getString("url");
     try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            doc.select(".topic .clear").remove();
            String title = doc.title().toString();
            html = doc.select(".username strong, .entry-content").toString();
            html = "<html><head><title>"+title+"</title></head><body><h1>"+title+"</h1>"+html+"</body></html>";
            WebView webview = new WebView(this);
             getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
             setContentView(webview);
             webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             final Activity activity = this;
             webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                     Log.d("LOADING",""+ progress);
                   }
                 });
             webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
             //webview.loadUrl(url);
            Log.i("HTML RETREIVED", ""+html);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error while generate topic");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've found out something interesting.

The class I wanted to select was not here because I'm getting the mobile version of the webpage. It appears Android App use a mobile user-agent, which is quite normal but not said anywhere.

Anyway I know what thinking about now.

Comment: I was just going to get my head off!
hahahaha!
same problem with me, thank you man!!